Running into MSSQLSERVER_701 "insufficient memory in the resource pool to run the SQL queries" when Azure SQL backup runs
We have a VM that was on-prem, but we recently moved it into Azure. The VM hosts a SQL Server instance with a few databases on it.
After setting up a schedule of SQL database backups through Azure, we've consistently encountered an error:
SQL ErrorNumber: 701
There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
 
Error: 3271, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.

BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

The alert points to this Microsoft link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2087433
Prior to moving our VM into Azure, I don't believe we ever encountered this error during SQL backups, nor do I recall seeing it for other transactions (part of why I don't have much experience troubleshooting memory errors). I'm able to back up these databases in SQL Server Management Studio without issue, and our previous product for taking backups didn't throw this error either.
Has anyone else encountered issues like this after moving a SQL Server instance and its VM into Azure? Given these details, I would greatly appreciate any recommendations as to where I should begin troubleshooting this issue.

'schedule of SQL database backups through Azure' do you mean this process? What is your target when you are doing successful backup via SSMS?

That might be the process...  I'm not the one who originally set up these backup schedules in Azure, but I know we're going into the Azure portal, creating backup policies, and assigning them to SQL Databases in Azure VM.  We've typically been doing a full backup once a week, differential backups nightly, and transaction log backups every 15 minutes.

By "target", you mean where does the backup file reside when backing up through SSMS?  On the same server on a drive set up for holding SQL backups.  We haven't regularly backed up our databases through SSMS in a few years, just in special circumstances.

I do notice that the error is occurring most frequently on a specific server; the rest of them seem fine so far.  The only thing jumping out at me about this server is that, unlike most of our others, it hosts three different SQL Servers.  Is it possible to run into a memory issue like this if too many different backups are getting triggered on the same server at the same time?  Wondering if we need to set up different schedules for different instances on this server so that they aren't competing for memory.

The issue does appear to be too many backup jobs running on the same server at the same time.  There are multiple SQL instances on the same server, and their backup schedules were for the same time.  After making adjustments so that different instances were on different schedules to lighten the load, we haven't been seeing the errors since.
